# Counting how many items can be weight on a scale if we pick the weights optimally

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, puzzle, ternary-expansion

I am reading about a problem that states the following:

> Suppose you have a balance and are allowed to choose the weights for
> its functionality. The objective is to pick the weights in a way that
> maximizes the number of items we can check by the scale.   Given $n$
> weights all of which are different how many different ways are there
> to arrange them on the scales of the balance? Assuming that the two
> sides of the balance are indistinguishable what conclusion can we make
> about the max range of items that we can use the scale to weigh?

The solution logic goes as follows:

> Each weight can be placed on the left scale, the right scale or on the
> table. These are 3 options so for $n$ weights we have $3^n$
> configurations of the balance.   One of these is symmetric between
> left and right scale (when no weights are on the scales). The rest are
> asymmetric between the left and right scale. Which means the same
> configuration is counted twice.

So far it is clear.
So we would have for e.g. ${1gram, 2gram}$:

```
Left, Right, Table
  -    -      (1,2) (--)
  1    -      (2)  
  -    1      (2)  (*)  
  2    -      (1)  
  -    2      (1)  (*)
  1    2      (-)  
  2    1      (-)  (*)
  1,2  -      (-)  
  -    1,2    (-)  (*)
```

So we would have all the marked with $*$ as duplicates and the $--$ i.e. all on the table as the symmetric one we exclude since no weights are on the scales.

But then it states:

> The total number of different configurations is $\frac{3^n - 1}2 + 1$

Where is the $+1$ coming from?

Going over an example for e.g. $n = 2$ for example $1gram, 3gram$
We can measure items of ${1gram, 2gram, 3gram, 4gram}$ which is a total of $\frac{3^2 - 1}2 =4$ and not $5$ as the solution claims.

Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: @RobPratt: No because I know how to derive the type. The $+1$ was the confusion on

Comment: please consider formatting your table using the newly available GitHub-flavored markdown syntax: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support

Comment: Why was this question closed? There is already an accepted answer for it

Comment: you may try posting in the request for undeletion/reopening on meta : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28692/290189

Comment: Per the dialog at the top of the question, this answer was closed because the users who voted to close it regarded it as a duplicate question, i.e. they feel that the question is answered elsewhere.  The fact that you have accepted an answer here is irrelevant to that.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: Thank you for checking my post. The other question is about proving that a similar formula to the one in my post solves the problem. My question is about why the specific formula in my post has an $+1$ and it was because of what the answer says i.e. include `weight =0` case

Comment: @Jim You are making a different argument, now.  Initially, you seemed to be arguing that the post should be reopened because it had an accepted answer.  Now you are arguing that it should be reopened because it is not a duplicate.  In response to *that* argument, I must admit that I am on the side of the close voters:  the questions are very closely related, and the answers to the older question, if read carefully, address this newer question.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: Ok, thank you for your input. I have one last question please. How should I have proceeded to find that similar question in the future? Is it possible to search by equation? Because for me doing searches with general terms does not lead very good results in general.

Comment: @Jim In general, you should try to search for previous posts.  The SE search tool is sometimes useful, but misses a lot.  There are other tools outlined [in this meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29265/).  That being said, posting a duplicate question is not a huge problem, particularly when it is clear, motivated, and well-written (as your post is at this moment in time).  Closing a question as a duplicate is not a punishment, and does not hurt your ability to post new questions---it simply helps to organize the content on the site.  In short, you did nothing wrong. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The +1 term comes from weighing zero grams, where there are no weights on either side.

Comment: So I should be counting that I can measure ${0grams, 1grams, 2grams, 3grams, 4grams}$ which is 5 for $n = 2$ I gave as example? Seems odd that we measure $0grams$

Comment: @Jim I agree that it is odd, but it is the only reasonable interpretation.

Comment: @Jim: It’s not so odd if you imagine that you always put the thing to be weighed on the left side and allow that thing to have negative weight (e.g., by attaching a helium-filled balloon to the pan): then you actually get all $3^n$ possible integral amounts from $-\frac{3^n-1}2$ to $\frac{3^n-1}2$, inclusive. Think of it as a physical model of [balanced ternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_ternary).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I didn't understand the `by attaching a helium-filled balloon to the pan`. What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Jim: That amounts to putting a negative weight in the pan, since the balloon rises. If it exerts a one ounce force upwards, you have in effect put a $-1$ ounce weight in the pan.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Ah by pan you mean on the e.g. left scale? But then if it has a negative weight we can't put any weight on the right scale to measure. So how can this be captured as the fifth measurement? Unless I completely misunderstood you

Comment: @Jim: (*Scale* refers to the whole apparatus; the left and right platforms are customarily called *pans*.) Suppose that you have a $1$ ounce and a $3$ ounce weight. You can weigh $-2$ ounces in the left pan by placing the $3$ ounce weight in the left pan and the $1$ ounce weight in the right pan. In the notation of the article to which I linked earlier, this corresponds to writing $-2$ in balanced ternary notation as $\top 1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I see, but doesn't that then make the range of items to weigh more than $\frac{3^n-1}2 + 1$ that the solution states?

Comment: @Jim: Of course. The point is that in this model it’s quite clear that it makes sense to weigh something with zero weight, since in fact we are weighing everything from $-m$ to $m$ for some $m\in\Bbb Z^+$. If you make the two sides of the balance indistinguishable, you lose the possibility of weighing negative weights, but you can still weigh zero ounces.